# Should we merge these two microwave convection questions?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

There is the older [Can I bake in a convection microwave?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56231/can-i-bake-in-a-convection-microwave) and the newer [Can microwave with convection replace an actual oven?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/56564/can-microwave-with-convection-replace-an-actual-oven?noredirect=1). We closed the newer as a duplicate.

We have several questions on baking in microwaves, many of whose answers say similar things, so maybe we don't need both of these duplicates to stay around. If we merge, I'd prefer the old->new direction, as the new question has a better quality and the asker is an established user while the old question was asked by a single-visit user.

On the other hand, maybe the wording is sufficiently different that it is better to keep both questions, so people who search for either wording will find information for their search.

What do you think? Do you have any pros or cons for either option?

Comment: I don't think they're strictly duplicates. One asks about baking specifically, the other as a more general replacement.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the content of the older question, which is more to the point and not about a specific model of oven. And I prefer the title of the newer question which subsumes that of the older.

If the questions are merged, and I think they should be, the question could be changed to read:

> **Can a convection microwave replace an electric oven?**
>
> Is a [convection microwave](http://www.kitchenaid.com/shop/major-appliances-1/microwaves-2/microwaves-3/-%5BKMBP107ESS%5D-407653/KMBP107ESS/) capable of being used as a replacement for a
>   conventional electric oven? Can they be used for roasting, 
>   making casseroles and, in particular, baking? If so, how do the results
>   compare?